# SQL Combining Multiple SELECT Statements

Tags: mysql, sql, sqlite, datetime, aggregate-functions

I am trying to build an SQLite query that will collect statistics from a single table.

The table holds a log, of sorts, with several entries per day. I need to get a separate row for each day within the search parameters and then compile the totals of rows within those dates with certain boolean values.

Here is the query I have so far:

```
SELECT DATE(DateTime) AS SearchDate,
     (SELECT COUNT() AS Total
                FROM CallRecords
                WHERE DATE(DateTime)
                BETWEEN '2017-08-27' AND '2017-09-02'
                GROUP BY DATE(DateTime)
                ORDER BY Total DESC) AS Total,
    (SELECT COUNT() AS Total
                FROM CallRecords
                WHERE NoMarket = 1
                AND DATE(DateTime)
                BETWEEN '2017-08-27' AND '2017-09-02'
                GROUP BY DATE(DateTime)
                ORDER BY Total DESC) AS NoMarkets,
    (SELECT COUNT() AS Total
                FROM CallRecords
                WHERE Complaint = 1
                AND DATE(DateTime)
                BETWEEN '2017-08-27' AND '2017-09-02'
                GROUP BY DATE(DateTime)
                ORDER BY Total DESC) AS Complaints,
    (SELECT COUNT() AS Total
                FROM CallRecords
                WHERE Voicemail = 1
                AND DATE(DateTime)
                BETWEEN '2017-08-27' AND '2017-09-02'
                GROUP BY DATE(DateTime)
                ORDER BY Total DESC) AS Voicemails
FROM CallRecords
WHERE DATE(DateTime) BETWEEN '2017-08-27' AND '2017-09-02'
GROUP BY SearchDate
```

And the output:

```
8/28/2017   175 27      11
8/29/2017   175 27      11
8/30/2017   175 27      11
8/31/2017   175 27      11
9/1/2017    175 27      11
```

As you can see, it is properly getting each individual date, but the totals for the columns is incorrect.

Obviously, I am missing something in my query, but I am not sure where. Is there a better way to perform this query?

EDIT: I have looked into several of the other questions with near-identical titles here, but I have not found anything similar to what I'm looking for.  Most seem much more complicated than what I'm trying to accomplish.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]. https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: @Yunnosch How do I do that without providing the actual database as well?

Comment: By providing the `.dump` from SQLite command line tool for a suitably tailored toy database.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It looks like you have a mess of columns in your `CallRecords` table with names like `Complaint` and `Voicemail`, each of which classifies a call.

It looks like those columns have the value 1 when relevant.

So this query should probably help you.

```
SELECT DATE(DateTime) AS SearchDate,
       COUNT(*) AS Total,
       SUM(NoMarket = 1) AS NoMarkets,
       SUM(Complaint = 1) AS Complaints,
       SUM(Voicemail = 1) AS Voicemails
  FROM CallRecords
 WHERE DateTime >=  '2017-08-27'
   AND DateTime <   '2017-09-02' + INTERVAL 1 DAY
 GROUP BY DATE(DateTime)
```

Why does this work? Because in MySQL a Boolean expression like `Voicemail = 1` has the value `1` when it's true and `0` when it's false. You can sum those values up quite nicely.

Why is it faster than what you have? Because `DATE(DateTime) BETWEEN this AND that` can't exploit an index on `DateTime`.

Why is it correct for the end of your date range? Because  `DateTime < '2017-09-02' + INTERVAL 1 DAY` pulls in all the records up until, but not including, midnight, on the day *after* your date range.

If you're using Sqlite, you need `AND DateTime < date('2017-09-02', '+1 day')`. The `+ INTERVAL 1 DAY` stuff is slightly different there.

Comment: `BETWEEN` is not the best choice of filtering operator for date ranges because it can be off by one on the end of the date range.

Comment: Brilliant. I don't know why I was trying to make it so complicated. However, I am using SQLite, not MySQL, so I couldn't use the `INTERVAL` part. I will adjust the dates in the query from the calling application.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

you can doing like this , although i wrote in SQL server

```
SELECT DATE(DateTime) AS SearchDate,
    COUNT() AS TOTAL,
    SUM(CASE WHEN NoMarket = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS NoMarkets,
    SUM(CASE WHEN Complaint = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Complaints,
    SUM(CASE WHEN Voicemail = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Voicemails
FROM CallRecords
WHERE DATE(DateTime) BETWEEN '2017-08-27' AND '2017-09-02'
GROUP BY SearchDate
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT DATE(DateTime) AS SearchDate, Total, NoMarkets, Complaints, Voicemails FROM
 (SELECT COUNT() AS Total FROM CallRecords) CR
 JOIN
(SELECT COUNT() AS NoMarkets FROM CallRecords WHERE NoMarket = 1) NM
 ON CR.DateTime = NM.DateTime
 JOIN
(SELECT COUNT() AS Complaints FROM CallRecords WHERE Complaint = 1) C
 ON NM.DateTime = C.DateTime
 JOIN
(SELECT COUNT() AS Voicemails FROM CallRecords WHERE Voicemail = 1) VM
 ON C.DateTime = VM.DateTime
 JOIN CallRecords CLR ON VM.DateTime=CLR.DateTime WHERE DATE(CLR.DateTime) >= '2017-08-27' AND DATE(CLR.DateTime) <= '2017-09-02'GROUP BY SearchDate;
```

This may Output correctly.

Comment: The virtual table named `NM` has no `DateTime` column. Same is true for the others. So the JOINs won't work.

Comment: Than how records are stored according to date in database table?